# How to configure Proxy in Aiogram 3.1.1 （Python)

Tags: python, proxy, aiogram

```
import asyncio

from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message

token = 'tokentokentokentokentokentokentoken'
the_bot = Bot(token)
main_handler = Dispatcher()

@main_handler.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(msg: Message) -> None:
    await msg.answer('hi')

async def main():
    await main_handler.start_polling(the_bot)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

[getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF9Vm.png)

Running a Telegram bot off of my own computer. I live in Xi'An China so I can't get to the API because Telegram is blocked here.
wath do?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Aiogram 3.1.1 didnot natively support proxy configuration, to use proxy for, you typically needed to use external Python libraries like aiosocksy or aiohttp. These libraries can be used to route your bot requests through a proxy server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this

```
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.client.session.aiohttp import AiohttpSession

session = AiohttpSession(proxy="protocol://host:port/")
bot = Bot(token="bot token", session=session)
```